# What's the difference between __popcnt() and _mm_popcnt_u32()?

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics, sse4

MS Visual C++ supports 2 flavors of the popcnt instruction on CPUs with SSE4.2:

1. [`__popcnt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
2. [`_mm_popcnt_u32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514083%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

The only difference I found was that the docs for `__popcnt()` are marked as "Microsoft Specific", and `_mm_popcnt_u32()` [seems to be an intrinsic command name](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/cpp/lin/intref_cls/common/intref_sse42_ATA.htm) (non-MS-specific).

Is this the only difference, where the MS `__popcnt()` just calls the HW `_mm_popcnt_u32()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**These are two different intrinsic names for the same machine instruction, thanks to Intel and AMD.**  The instruction is the same on all CPUs that support it, and the different intrinsics also have no difference in C or C++.

---

The __popcnt*() builtins are for AMD's Advanced Bit Manipulation (ABM) instructions. See http://blogs.amd.com/developer/2007/09/26/barcelona-processor-feature-advanced-bit-manipulation-abm/

The _mm_popcnt_u*() intrinsics are for Intel's implementation, which aren't part of SSE4.2 per se, but were implemented around the same time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT

According to https://www.chessprogramming.org/Population_Count , both implementations are binary compatible, in spite of their different intrinsic names.

Intel's [architecture manual](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf) states that:

> Before an application attempts to use the POPCNT instruction, it must check that the
>   processor supports SSE4.2 (if CPUID.01H:ECX.SSE4_2[bit 20] = 1) and POPCNT (if
>   CPUID.01H:ECX.POPCNT[bit 23] = 1).

AMD's [AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 3: General Purpose and System Instructions](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24594_APM_v3.pdf) says

> Support for the POPCNT instruction is indicated by ECX bit 23 (POPCNT) as returned by CPUID
>   function 0000_0001h. Software MUST check the CPUID bit once per program or library initialization
>   before using the POPCNT instruction, or inconsistent behavior may result.

I can't see any reason why popcnt would require the presence of SSE4.2, so I think that checking bit 23 of ECX is sufficient to determine popcnt's presence.

---

AMD's Barcelona, the first AMD CPU to have popcnt, didn't fully implement SSE4, so it's possible that Intel's architecture manual suggests a method for determine presence which will work on Intel CPUs and fail on even qualified AMD CPUs.

**Intel's current [documentation for `popcnt`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPCNT.html) in their vol.2 instruction-set reference manual only says `#UD If CPUID.01H:ECX.POPCNT [Bit 23] = 0`** so the anti-competitive suggestion that would lead to software not taking advantage of `popcnt` on some AMD CPUs without SSE4.2 is gone.

Comment: So is there a difference in when to use each in software? Should a different cpuid bit be checked? If I want to write Intel/AMD agnostic cwhat that still utilizes the command, what should I do?

Comment: It does not appear that they are different or incompatible. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Intel's insn ref entry for [`popcnt`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPCNT.html) currently just says `#UD  If CPUID.01H:ECX.POPCNT [Bit 23] = 0`, so the unhelpful / anti-competitive suggestion to check for SSE4.2 isn't present there.