# Fast counting the number of set bits in __m128i register

Tags: c, sse, simd, sse2, hammingweight

I should count the number of set bits of a __m128i register.
In particular, I should write two functions that are able to count the number of bits of the register, using the following ways.

1. The total number of set bits of the register.
2. The number of set bits for each byte of the register.

Are there intrinsic functions that can perform, wholly or partially, the above operations?

Comment: Recent CPUs have a `POPCNT` (population count) instruction; GCC exposes it via the [`__builtin_popcount`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) built-in.

Comment: See http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html for this and much more.

Comment: MS also has popcount functions ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114017/whats-the-difference-between-popcnt-and-mm-popcnt-u32 ... Note that these are not necessarily faster than the bithacks; and if counting bits in arrays, some of the bithack functions are somewhat faster.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here are some codes I used in an old project ([there is a research paper about it](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2389097)). The function `popcnt8` below computes the number of bits set in each byte.

SSE2-only version (based on Algorithm 3 in [Hacker's Delight book](http://www.hackersdelight.org/)):

```
static const __m128i popcount_mask1 = _mm_set1_epi8(0x77);
static const __m128i popcount_mask2 = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F);
static inline __m128i popcnt8(__m128i x) {
    __m128i n;
    // Count bits in each 4-bit field.
    n = _mm_srli_epi64(x, 1);
    n = _mm_and_si128(popcount_mask1, n);
    x = _mm_sub_epi8(x, n);
    n = _mm_srli_epi64(n, 1);
    n = _mm_and_si128(popcount_mask1, n);
    x = _mm_sub_epi8(x, n);
    n = _mm_srli_epi64(n, 1);
    n = _mm_and_si128(popcount_mask1, n);
    x = _mm_sub_epi8(x, n);
    x = _mm_add_epi8(x, _mm_srli_epi16(x, 4));
    x = _mm_and_si128(popcount_mask2, x);
    return x;
}
```

SSSE3 version (due to [Wojciech Mula](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html)):

```
static const __m128i popcount_mask = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F);
static const __m128i popcount_table = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4);
static inline __m128i popcnt8(__m128i n) {
    const __m128i pcnt0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(popcount_table, _mm_and_si128(n, popcount_mask));
    const __m128i pcnt1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(popcount_table, _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi16(n, 4), popcount_mask));
    return _mm_add_epi8(pcnt0, pcnt1);
}
```

XOP version (equivalent to SSSE3, but uses XOP instructions which are faster on AMD Bulldozer)

```
static const __m128i popcount_mask = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F);
static const __m128i popcount_table = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4);
static const __m128i popcount_shift = _mm_set1_epi8(-4);
static inline __m128i popcount8(__m128i n) {
    const __m128i pcnt0 = _mm_perm_epi8(popcount_table, popcount_table, _mm_and_si128(n, popcount_mask));
    const __m128i pcnt1 = _mm_perm_epi8(popcount_table, popcount_table, _mm_shl_epi8(n, popcount_shift));
    return _mm_add_epi8(pcnt0, pcnt1);
}
```

Function `popcnt64` below counts the number of bits in the low and high 64-bit parts of the SSE register:

SSE2 version:

```
static inline __m128i popcnt64(__m128i n) {
    const __m128i cnt8 = popcnt8(n);
    return _mm_sad_epu8(cnt8, _mm_setzero_si128());
}
```

XOP version:

```
static inline __m128i popcnt64(__m128i n) {
    const __m128i cnt8 = popcnt8(n);
    return _mm_haddq_epi8(cnt8);
}
```

Finally, the function `popcnt128` below count the number of bits in the whole 128-bit register:

```
static inline int popcnt128(__m128i n) {
    const __m128i cnt64 = popcnt64(n);
    const __m128i cnt64_hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(cnt64, cnt64);
    const __m128i cnt128 = _mm_add_epi32(cnt64, cnt64_hi);
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(cnt128);
}
```

However, a more efficient way to implement `popcnt128` is to use hardware POPCNT instruction (on processors which support it):

```
static inline int popcnt128(__m128i n) {
    const __m128i n_hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(n, n);
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        return __popcnt64(_mm_cvtsi128_si64(n)) + __popcnt64(_mm_cvtsi128_si64(n_hi));
    #else
        return __popcntq(_mm_cvtsi128_si64(n)) + __popcntq(_mm_cvtsi128_si64(n_hi));
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are one of the co-authors of the mentioned research paper :-) Nice summary for the cut'n'paste crew as well. Your solutions are up to date. The Hakem tricks aren't up to date anymore. Kudos, dude!

Comment: Oh, so bad. You published your paper at the ACM, so I can't unfortunately read it without paying $15 :-(

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck, the paper is freely available on the conference website: conferences.computer.org/sc/2012/papers/1000a033.pdf

Comment: Apparently, your SSE2 version is usually faster than your SSSE3 version. It doesn’t matters SSSE3 have less instructions. Here’s a benchmark:  https://github.com/Const-me/LookupTables

Comment: @Soonts It could be, but results from Microsoft compiler alone are not convincing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version base on [Bit Twiddling Hacks - Counting Set Bits in Parallel](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) with naming similar to other intrinsic functions as well as some extra functions for 16 32 and 64 bit vectors

```
#include "immintrin.h"

/* bit masks: 0x55 = 01010101, 0x33 = 00110011, 0x0f = 00001111 */
static const __m128i m1 = {0x5555555555555555ULL,0x5555555555555555ULL};
static const __m128i m2 = {0x3333333333333333ULL,0x3333333333333333ULL};
static const __m128i m3 = {0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fULL,0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fULL};
static const __m128i m4 = {0x001f001f001f001fULL,0x001f001f001f001fULL};
static const __m128i m5 = {0x0000003f0000003fULL,0x0000003f0000003fULL};

__m128i _mm_popcnt_epi8(__m128i x) {
    /* Note: if we returned x here it would be like _mm_popcnt_epi1(x) */ 
    __m128i y;
    /* add even and odd bits*/
    y = _mm_srli_epi64(x,1);  //put even bits in odd place
    y = _mm_and_si128(y,m1);  //mask out the even bits (0x55)
    x = _mm_subs_epu8(x,y);   //shortcut to mask even bits and add
    /* if we just returned x here it would be like _mm_popcnt_epi2(x) */ 
    /* now add the half nibbles */
    y = _mm_srli_epi64 (x,2); //move half nibbles in place to add
    y = _mm_and_si128(y,m2);  //mask off the extra half nibbles (0x0f)
    x = _mm_and_si128(x,m2);  //ditto
    x = _mm_adds_epu8(x,y);   //totals are a maximum of 5 bits (0x1f)
    /* if we just returned x here it would be like _mm_popcnt_epi4(x) */ 
    /* now add the nibbles */
    y = _mm_srli_epi64(x,4);  //move nibbles in place to add
    x = _mm_adds_epu8(x,y);   //totals are a maximum of 6 bits (0x3f)
    x = _mm_and_si128(x,m3);  //mask off the extra bits
    return x;
}

__m128i _mm_popcnt_epi16(__m128i x) {
    __m128i y;
    x = _mm_popcnt_epi8(x);    //get byte popcount
    y = _mm_srli_si128(x,1);   //copy even bytes for adding
    x = _mm_add_epi16(x,y);    //add even bytes into the odd bytes
    return _mm_and_si128(x,m4);//mask off the even byte and return
}

__m128i _mm_popcnt_epi32(__m128i x) {
    __m128i y;
    x = _mm_popcnt_epi16(x);   //get word popcount
    y = _mm_srli_si128(x,2);   //copy even words for adding
    x = _mm_add_epi32(x,y);    //add even words into odd words
    return _mm_and_si128(x,m5);//mask off the even words and return
}

__m128i _mm_popcnt_epi64(__m128i x){
    /* _mm_sad_epu8() is weird
       It takes the absolute difference of bytes between 2 __m128i
       then horizontal adds the lower and upper 8 differences
       and stores the sums in the lower and upper 64 bits
    */
    return _mm_sad_epu8(_mm_popcnt_epi8(x),(__m128i){0});
}

int _mm_popcnt_si128(__m128i x){
    x = _mm_popcnt_epi64(x);
    __m128i y = _mm_srli_si128(x,8);
    return _mm_add_epi64(x,y)[0];
    //alternative: __builtin_popcntll(x[0])+__builtin_popcntll(x[1]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need saturating `adds` instead of regular `add` for  the steps after the very first?  (Although according to Agner Fog's instruction tables, `paddusb` has the same performance as `paddb` on everything, so there's no perf reason to avoid saturating add.  It's just surprising.)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the first comment, gcc 3.4+ offers an easy access to a (hopefully optimal) built-in via

```
int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x) /* Returns the number of 1-bits in x. */
```

As stated here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other%20Builtins

Does not exactly answer the question for 128bits, but give a nice answer to the question I had when I landed here :)

Answer (score -3):

Edit: I guess I didn't understand what the OP was looking for, but I am keeping my answer up in case it is useful to anyone else stumbling across this.

C provides some nice bitwise operations.

Here is code to count the number of bits set in an integer:

```
countBitsSet(int toCount)
{
    int numBitsSet = 0;
    while(toCount != 0)
    {
        count += toCount % 2;
        toCount = toCount >> 1;
    }
    return numBitsSet;
}
```

Explanation:

```
toCount % 2
```

Returns the last bit in our integer. (By dividing by two and checking the remainder).  We add this to our total count, and then shift the bits of our toCount value by one.  This operation should be continued until there are no more bits set in toCount (when toCount is equal to 0)

To count the number of bits in a specific byte, you will want to use a mask.  Here is an example:

```
countBitsInByte(int toCount, int byteNumber)
{
    int mask = 0x000F << byteNumber * 8
    return countBitsSet(toCount & mask)
}
```

Lets say that in our system, we consider byte 0 the least significant byte in a little endian system.  We want to create a new toCount to pass to our earlier countBitsSet function by masking out the bits that are set to 0.  We do this by shifting a byte full of ones (denoted by the letter F) to the position we want (byteNumber * 8 for 8 bits in a byte) and performing a bitwise AND operation with our toCount variable.

Comment: There *are* built-ins (intrinsics which map to CPU instructions such as `POPCNT`) and the question is about counting set bits in a 128 bit SSE (XMM) register, not an `int`.

Comment: Ah, I see I didn't completely understand the question. If it is appropriate I will edit my response and keep it up in case it is helpful to someone stumbling across this.

Comment: C doesn't provide "nice" bitwise operations.  You can't even portably get an arithmetic right shift!  Implementations are allowed to be 2's complement but have `>>` on a signed type be a logical shift.  But in practice all the compilers people actually want to use give you arithmetic right shift on signed types, and thus your function is an infiinite loop for negative `toCount`.  And signed `%2` takes much more work than `&1`, because it has to produce `-1` for negative odd numbers.  But (on normal compilers) your function never returns if `toCount` was negative, so that problem is hidden...