# How do I vectorize data_i16[0 to 15]?

Tags: c++, arrays, sse, simd, lookup-tables

I'm on [the Intel Intrinsic site](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide) and I can't figure out what combination of instructions I want. What I'd like to do is

```
result = high_table[i8>>4] & low_table[i8&15]
```

Where both table are 16bits (or more). shuffle seems like what I want (_mm_shuffle_epi8) however getting a 8bit value doesn't work for me. There doesn't seem to be a 16bit version and the non byte version seems to need the second param as an immediate value.

How am I suppose to implement this? Do I call _mm_shuffle_epi8 twice for each table, cast it to 16bits and shift the value by 8? If so which cast and shift instruction do I want to look at?

Comment: Unless your question is truly language-agnostic, please include a tag for the language.

Comment: AVX2 has `vpermd` : select dwords from a vector of 8x 32-bit elements.  But other than that, yeah `pshufb` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) is the way to go *if* your lookup table is separable.  (i.e. the lookup based on the upper nibble doesn't depend on the lower nibble).  Then sure, do that twice and AND them together.

Comment: You're talking about concatenating the bits, but  `&` in C is bitwise AND.  I think you actually mean `(high_table[u8>>4]  << 8) | low_table[u8 & 0xf]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not good at reading intels psuedo code but vpermd could be a solution. No I mean if I were to use 2 8bit looks up for high table I'd do `(highA<<8 | highB) & (lowA<<8 | lowB)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To split your incoming indices into two vectors of nibbles, you want the usual bit-shift and AND.  SSE doesn't have 8-bit shifts, so you have to emulate with a wider shift and an AND to mask away bits that shifted into the top of your bytes.  (Because unfortunately for this use-case `_mm_shuffle_epi8` does not ignore the high bits.  If the top selector bit is set it zeros that output element.)

You definitely do *not* want to widen your incoming `i8` vector to 16-bit elements; that would not be usable with `_mm_shuffle_epi8`.

---

AVX2 has `vpermd` : select dwords from a vector of 8x 32-bit elements.  (only 3-bit indices so it's not good for your use-case unless your nibbles are only 0..7).  AVX512BW has wider shuffles, including `vpermi2w` to index into a table of the concatenation of two vectors, or just `vpermw` to index words.

But for 128-bit vectors with just SSSE3, yeah `pshufb` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) is the way to go.  You'll need two separate vectors for `high_table`, one for the upper byte and one for the lower byte of each word entry.  And another two vectors for the halves of low_table.

**Use `_mm_unpacklo_epi8` and `_mm_unpackhi_epi8` to interleave the low 8 bytes of two vectors, or the high 8 bytes of two vectors**.  That will give you the 16-bit LUT results you want, with the upper half in each word coming from the high-half vector.

i.e. you're building a 16-bit LUT out of two 8-bit LUTs with this interleave.  And you're repeating the process twice for two different LUTs.

---

The code would look something like

```
// UNTESTED, haven't tried even compiling this.

// produces 2 output vectors, you might want to just put this in a loop instead of making a helper function for 1 vector.
// so I'll omit actually returning them.
void foo(__m128i indices)
{
   // these optimize away, only used at compile time for the vector initializers
   static const uint16_t high_table[16] = {...},
   static const uint16_t low_table[16] =  {...};

   // each LUT needs a separate vector of high-byte and low-byte parts
   // don't use SIMD intrinsics to load from the uint16_t tables and deinterleave at runtime, just get the same 16x 2 x 2 bytes of data into vector constants at compile time.
   __m128i high_LUT_lobyte = _mm_setr_epi8(high_table[0]&0xff, high_table[1]&0xff, high_table[2]&0xff, ... );
   __m128i high_LUT_hibyte = _mm_setr_epi8(high_table[0]>>8, high_table[1]>>8, high_table[2]>>8, ... );

   __m128i low_LUT_lobyte = _mm_setr_epi8(low_table[0]&0xff, low_table[1]&0xff, low_table[2]&0xff, ... );
   __m128i low_LUT_hibyte = _mm_setr_epi8(low_table[0]>>8, low_table[1]>>8, low_table[2]>>8, ... );


// split the input indexes: emulate byte shift with wider shift + AND
    __m128i lo_idx = _mm_and_si128(indices, _mm_set1_epi8(0x0f));
    __m128i hi_idx = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi32(indices, 4), _mm_set1_epi8(0x0f));

    __m128i lolo = _mm_shuffle_epi8(low_LUT_lobyte, lo_idx);
    __m128i lohi = _mm_shuffle_epi8(low_LUT_hibyte, lo_idx);

    __m128i hilo = _mm_shuffle_epi8(high_LUT_lobyte, hi_idx);
    __m128i hihi = _mm_shuffle_epi8(high_LUT_hibyte, hi_idx);

   // interleave results of LUT lookups into vectors 16-bit elements
    __m128i low_result_first  = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(lolo, lohi);
    __m128i low_result_second = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(lolo, lohi);
    __m128i high_result_first  = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(hilo, hihi);
    __m128i high_result_second = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(hilo, hihi);

    // first 8x 16-bit high_table[i8>>4] & low_table[i8&15] results
    __m128i and_first = _mm_and_si128(low_result_first, high_result_first);
    // second 8x 16-bit high_table[i8>>4] & low_table[i8&15] results
    __m128i and_second = _mm_and_si128(low_result_second, high_result_second);

    // TOOD: do something with the results.
}
```

You could AND before interleaving, high halves against high halves and low against low.  That might be somewhat better for instruction-level parallelism, letting execution of the ANDs overlap with the shuffles.  (Intel Haswell through Skylake has only 1/clock throughput for shuffles.)

Choosing variable names is a struggle with stuff like this.  Some people just give up and use non-meaningful names for some intermediate steps.

Comment: Sounds good. Just to confirm I understand. I need to split my 16bit high_table into highA highB both being 8 bits. I call _mm_shuffle_epi8 for both of them. Then I call _mm_unpacklo_epi8(A, B) which is essentially `(B<<8)|A`. But that only gets me 8 16bit. Calling _mm_unpackhi_epi8 gets me the other `8x16`. Then I repeat this for my second table and and them like the original code does. I think I understood correctly. Sounds like a good plan (and writing this out helps me think)

Comment: @EricStotch: after seeing your comment under the question I revised my answer based on what you're actually doing: two separate 16-entry LUTs of 16-bit words separately indexed by input nibbles that just happen to be packed together.  Not trying to emulate a 256-entry LUT of 16-bit words with an 8-bit index, which is what I was answering before (works if they're separable, like in some Galois Field and other use cases.)

Comment: Anyway yes, your overall thing will handle 16 bytes of input nibble-pairs by splitting them up with right-shift / 2xAND, then 4x pshufb on 4 different vectors of LUT data.  Then 2x punpcklbw and 2x punpckhbw, and 2x PAND to actually do the final AND, giving you 2 vectors (32 bytes) of 16x 16-bit results.

Comment: I'm awful at SIMD and need to find a book in the morning. It took me longer than it should to figure out the AND is _mm_and_si128 and it seems like I need to use 16bits for right shift (_mm_sra_epi16). I guess I'll need to use _mm_unpacklo_epi8 with 0's. At least I'm starting to get the hang of this

Comment: @EricStotch: x86 SIMD is notorious non-orthogonal with different element widths for the same operation added piecemeal in different SSE versions.  And e.g. shifts only available in some operand-sizes not including 8-bit.  But yeah, bitwise stuff doesn't have an element size so it's just `si128`.

Comment: But no you don't need to unpacklo with zeros; the usual way is to emulate a byte shift by doing a wider shift and ANDing with `0xf`.  You already need that vector constant for the low nibbles anyway.  **See [Fast counting the number of set bits in \_\_m128i register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17354971) for an example of unpacking bytes to low / high nibbles to feed a pshufb LUT**

Comment: I couldn't figure out the widing shift so I wrote a question. Hopefully someone else can answer it before you see this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446596/how-do-i-efficiently-lookup-16bits-in-a-128bit-simd-vector

Comment: @EricStotch: updated with an untested version.  IDK if it even compiles, but it's the right idea at least.

Comment: Thanks but I already wrote the code! It's the same except for variable names.

Comment: @EricStotch: Hopefully it will help future readers, then.  I thought there should be some actual code since I closed your other question as a duplicate of this, and you hadn't posted an answer here so I wasn't sure you weren't still stuck on some part of it.  Or that you'd made some efficiency mistake like loading from the 16-bit LUT arrays at runtime and using `_mm_pack_epi16` or something to make the LUT vectors.  It probably only took 10 minutes or so to type out the code I'd already been picturing.