# What's the purpose of looping "xorl %edx,%eax; shrl $1,%edx"?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, decompiling, att

I have the following x86 assembly code:

```
  movl   8(%ebp), %edx  //get an argument from the caller
  movl   $0, %eax
  testl  %edx, %edx
  je     .L1            
.L2:                   // what's the purpose of this loop body?
  xorl   %edx, %eax
  shrl   $1, %edx
  jne    .L2
.L1:
  andl   $1, %eax
```

The corresponding C code that the textbook gives as follows

```
int f1(unsigned x)
{
    int y = 0;
    while(x != 0) {
        __________;
    }
    return __________;
 }
```

The book asks readers to fill the blank and answer the question of "What does it do?"

I can't combine the loop body in one C expression. I can tell what the loop body does, but I have no idea about its purpose. The textbook also says that %eax here stores the return value. So...what's the purpose of

```
andl  $1, %eax
```

I also have no idea.

Comment: `xorl` is an xor (`^`) operation, while `shrl` is a right shift (`>>`)...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I think the OP knows that, but didn't put the pieces together of looking at just the low bit of the register that the loop updates.

Comment: @PeterCordes If the original poster knew that he would be able determine the equivalent C expression. You don't actually need to know the purpose the code to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @RossRidge: I think they were stuck on trying to do it with a single C expression, rather than `y ^= x;  x>>=1;` on one line.  Or am I also missing some single-expression way to express that in C (i.e. not the comma operator or separate statements.)  Of course, the reason I upvoted is for trying to grok what the function *does*, not just how to solve the fill-in-the-blank homework decompile question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the purpose of the whole loop is to XOR all the bits together in the 32-bit arg.  i.e. calculate the [**parity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit).

Working backwards from the last instruction (`and $1,%eax`), we know that only the low bit of the result matters.

With that in mind, the `xor %edx,%eax` becomes clearer: xor the current low bit of `%edx` into `%eax`.  The high garbage doesn't matter.

The `shr` loops until all of `x`'s bits have been shifted out.  We could always loop 32 times to get all the bits, but that would be less efficient than stopping once `x` is 0.  (Because of how XOR works, we don't need to actual XOR in the 0 bits; that has no effect.)

---

Once we know what the function does, filling in the C becomes an exercise in clever / compact C syntax.  I thought at first that `y ^= (x>>=1);` would fit inside the loop, but that shifts `x` *before* using it the first time.

The only way I see to do it in one C statement is with the `,` operator (which does introduce a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), so it's safe to read `x` on the left side and modify it on the right side of a `,`).  So, `y ^= x, x>>=1;` fits.

Or, for more readable code, just cheat and put two statements on the same line with a `;`.

```
int f1(unsigned x) {
    int y = 0;
    while(x != 0) {
        y ^= x;  x>>=1;      
    }
    return y & 1;
 }
```

**This compiles to essentially the same asm as shown in the question**, using [gcc5.3 -O3 on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fverbose-asm+-m32+-march%3Dnehalem',source:'int+f1(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++int+y+%3D+0%3B%0A++++while(x+!!%3D+0)+%7B%0A++++++++y+%5E%3D+x%3B++x%3E%3E%3D1%3B++++++%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+y+%26+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+remove+-march%3Dnehalem+to+see+what+gcc+does+without+the+popcnt+instruction%0Aint+parity_gnuc(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++return++__builtin_parity(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23ifdef+__POPCNT__%0A%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0Aint+parity_popcnt(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++return++_mm_popcnt_u32(x)+%26+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).  The question's code [de-optimizes the xor-zeroing idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295) to a `mov $0, %eax`, and optimizes gcc's silly duplication of `ret` instructions.  (Or maybe used an earlier version of gcc that didn't do that.)

---

#### The loop is very inefficient: this is an efficient way:

We don't need a loop with O(n) complexity (where n is the width in bits of `x`).  Instead, we can get O(log2(n)) complexity, and actually take advantage of x86 tricks to only do the first 2 steps of that.

I've left off the operand-size suffix for instructions where it's determined by the registers.  (Except for `xorw` to make the 16-bit xor explicit.)

```
#untested
parity:
    # no frame-pointer boilerplate

    xor       %eax,%eax        # zero eax (so the upper 24 bits of the int return value are zeroed).  And yes, this is more efficient than mov $0, %eax
                               # so when we set %al later, the whole of %eax will be good.

    movzwl    4(%esp), %edx      # load low 16 bits of `x`.  (zero-extend into the full %edx is for efficiency.  movw 4(%esp), %dx would work too.
    xorw      6(%esp), %dx       # xor the high 16 bits of `x`
    # Two loads instead of a load + copy + shift is probably a win, because cache is fast.
    xor       %dh, %dl           # xor the two 8 bit halves, setting PF according to the result
    setnp      %al               # get the inverse of the CPU's parity flag.  Remember that the rest of %eax is already zero, so the result is already zero-extended to 32-bits (int return value)
    ret
```

Yes, that's right, [x86 has a parity flag (`PF`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_flag) that's updated from the low 8 bits of the result of every instruction that "sets flags according to the result", like [`xor`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XOR.html).

We use the `np` condition because `PF` = 1 means even parity: xor of all bits = 0.  We need the inverse to return 0 for even parity.

To take advantage of it, we do a SIMD-style horizontal reduction by bringing the high half down to the low half and combining, repeating twice to reduce 32 bits to 8 bits.

Zeroing eax (with an xor) before the instruction that sets flags is slightly more efficient than doing set-flags / `setp %al` / `movzbl %al, %eax`, as I explained in [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295).

---

Or, as @EOF points out, if the CPUID [`POPCNT` feature bit is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114017/whats-the-difference-between-popcnt-and-mm-popcnt-u32), you can use popcnt and test the low bit to see if the number of set bits is even or odd.  (Another way to look at this: xor is add-without-carry, so the low bit is the same whether you xor all the bits together or add all the bits together horizontally).

GNU C also has `__builtin_parity` and `__builtin_popcnt` which use the hardware instruction if you tell the compiler that the compile target supports it (with `-march=...` or `-mpopcnt`), but otherwise compile to an efficient sequence for the target machine.  The Intel intrinsics always compile to the machine instruction, not a fallback sequence, and it's a compile-time error to use them without the appropriate `-mpopcnt` target option.

Unfortunately gcc doesn't recognize the pure-C loop as being a parity calculation and optimize it into this.  Some compilers (like clang and probably gcc) can recognize some kinds of popcount idioms, and optimize them into the `popcnt` instruction, but that kind of pattern recognition doesn't happen in this case. :(

[See these on godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fverbose-asm+-m32+-march%3Dnehalem',source:'int+f1(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++int+y+%3D+0%3B%0A++++while(x+!!%3D+0)+%7B%0A++++++++y+%5E%3D+x%3B++x%3E%3E%3D1%3B++++++%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+y+%26+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+remove+-march%3Dnehalem+to+see+what+gcc+does+without+the+popcnt+instruction%0Aint+parity_gnuc(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++return++__builtin_parity(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23ifdef+__POPCNT__%0A%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0Aint+parity_popcnt(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++++return++_mm_popcnt_u32(x)+%26+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

```
int parity_gnuc(unsigned x) {
    return  __builtin_parity(x);
}
    # with -mpopcnt, compiles the same as below
    # without popcnt, compiles to the same upper/lower half XOR algorithm I used, and a setnp
    # using one load and mov/shift for the 32->16 step, and still %dh, %dl for the 16->8 step.

#ifdef __POPCNT__
#include <immintrin.h>
int parity_popcnt(unsigned x) {
    return  _mm_popcnt_u32(x) & 1;
}
#endif

    # gcc does compile this to the optimal code:
    popcnt    4(%esp), %eax
    and       $1, %eax
    ret
```

---

See also other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: If you would be able to modify the code more, it would be possible to do it in simpler (1 less "statement") C++ source `int y = x; while (x>>=1) { y ^= x; } return y&1;` (while staying true to the original stupid way of calculating parity by xoring each bit)  ... but curiously according to godbolt it does procude a tiny bit worse machine code (one more `mov eax,edi` to your version). Don't want to discuss it here, but why I always expect more from compilers? :/ Like why it does not align the loop by moving the function start, but it puts NOP inside the fn body instead? I don't get it. :D

Comment: But the optimized method returns the opposite value? The PF is set when bits are even, while the original function returns 0 for even bits, if I didn't do some mistake. BTW, I didn't know the PF was affected only by low 8 bits till today... (after writing well over 1+MB of x86 ASM sources over decade) ... The learning process never stops.. :D

Comment: `popcount` + `and`.

Comment: Well, since you mention the assembly equivalent, I think it's also worth mentioning compiler-specific extensions such as `__builtin_parity` and/or `__builtin_popcount` at least for GCC et al. Good answer btw.

Comment: @Ped7g: thanks for the bugfix on the optimized version.  A good efficient algorithm was much more interesting than annoying complications like looking up the sense of PF to avoid inverting the answer :P  re: alignment: I don't think gcc even knows instruction sizes, and just has some tuneable heuristics for emitting `.p2align`.  After reporting a few missed-optimization bugs, I've realized that compilers aren't "smart", they're just very complicated but still dumb machines.  I agree it's disappointing that compilers aren't smart, but fast compile times preclude more than polynomial complexity.

Comment: @black: good point, the GNU C __builtin functions still work without enabling `-mpopcnt`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, the fact it doesn't need SSE support makes it more portable across platforms. OTOH, if you need it more portable across _compilers_, SSE is better given the common-agreed interface, as you say (assuming hardware support, clearly).

Comment: @black: Good point.  `popcnt` is separate from SSE (see the link about the CPUID feature bit), but yes, it's x86-only.  However, if you compile without `-mpopcnt`, you won't take advantage of the `popcnt` instruction even on hardware that does support it.  This is where a JIT-compiled language like Java has an advantage, since dynamic dispatching for tiny functions isn't viable (you could maybe dynamic dispatch larger functions that inline the parity function).

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful!