# How to check if exactly one bit is set in an int?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have an `std::uint32_t` and want to check if exactly one bit is set. How can I do this without iterating over all bits like this? In other words, can the following function be simplified?

```
static inline bool isExactlyOneBitSet(std::uint32_t bits)
{
    return ((bits & 1) == bits
        || (bits & 1 << 1) == bits
        || (bits & 1 << 2) == bits
        // ...
        || (bits & 1 << 31) == bits
        );
}
```

Bonus: It would be nice if the return value was the one found bit or else 0.

```
static inline bool isExactlyOneBitSet(std::uint32_t bits)
{
if (bits & 1) {return 1;}
else if  (bits & 1 << 1) {return 1 << 1;};
//...
else if  (bits & 1 << 31) {return 1 << 31;};

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The number which is 2^n are only numbers which has one bit set.

Comment: _exactly_ one or _at least_ one? Your first example checks for at least one, which is equivalent to `!= 0`.

Comment: `x && !(x & (x-1))`

Comment: Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053582/509868)

Comment: FWIW, C++20 will likely have [`std::ispow2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ispow2).

Comment: @tkausl fixed. I mean exactly one.

Comment: There are several other questions about this with great answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951776/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856596/ but none fulfills the bonus question...

Comment: Answer for the bonus: `return bits;`.

Comment: @Fabian solved it using log

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So you want to know **if a number is power of 2 or not**? Well there is a famous algorithm for that, you can simply do,

```
check_bit(std::uint32_t bits)
{
    return bits && !(bits & (bits-1));
}
```

Any power of 2 when subtracted by 1 is all `1s`. e.g,

```
4 - 1 = 3 (011)
8 - 1 = 7 (0111)
```

The bitwise and of any power of 2 and any number 1 less than it will give `0`. So we can verify if a number is power of 2 or not by using the expression, `n&(n-1)`.

It will fail when `n=0`, so we have to add an extra `and` condition.

For finding the position of bit, you can do:

```
int findSetBit(std::uint32_t bits)
{
    if (!(bits && !(bits & (bits-1))))
        return 0;
    return log2(bits) + 1;
}
```

### Extra Stuffs

In gcc, you can use `__builtin_popcount()`, to find the count of set bits in any number.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << __builtin_popcount (4) << "\n";
   std::cout << __builtin_popcount (3) << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Then check if count is equal to `1` or not.

Regarding count, there is another famous algorithm, **Brian Kernighan’s Algorithm**. Google it up, it finds count in `log(n)` time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114017/whats-the-difference-between-popcnt-and-mm-popcnt-u32 for an overview of the cross platform cross compiler variants of __buildtin_popcount

Comment: thanks for mentioning that link, the `popcount` function is compiler dependent.

Comment: In the bonus, isn't the desired value bits, not log2 of bits?

Comment: The op wants to find the position of the 'on' bit.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution for your bonus question (and of course, it is a solution for your original question as well):

```
std::uint32_t exactlyOneBitSet(std::uint32_t bits) {
    return bits&(((bool)(bits&(bits-1)))-1);
}
```

This compiles down to only 4 instructions on x86_64 with clang:

```
0000000000000000 <exactlyOneBitSet(unsigned int)>:
   0:   8d 4f ff                lea    -0x1(%rdi),%ecx
   3:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   5:   85 f9                   test   %edi,%ecx
   7:   0f 44 c7                cmove  %edi,%eax
   a:   c3                      retq
```

Answer (score 3):

C++20 has a function that does exactly that: [std::has_single_bit(value)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit).  It's in the header `<bit>`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a number `n`, the following expression will determine if exactly one bit is set (in any language): `(n & (n - 1)) == 0`.

To check if a number is exact power of 2, You can also use the expression `(n & (-n)) == n`.

In JavaScript, however, these expression fail at `-2^31`.

Note the bitwise AND (`&`) operator here.